# Google Maps and Revealing Module Pattern – Context

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I created a little function, which puts a map (Google Maps) on a website. To structure my code a bit i used the Revealing Module Pattern (multiple instances of the same module for multiple maps). On page load i load the Google Maps API with AJAX and then attach a click event listener to each marker.

I created a fiddle with the basic code: http://jsfiddle.net/K9mqz/.

If there is just one `.map` in my HTML it works just fine, but as soon as i put a second `.map` in my HTML and i click on a marker in the first map, the content gets shown in the second map. I'm not sure, but i think the part, which is broken is the part in my Google Maps API event listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListener( marker[ idx ], 'click', function( e ) {
       // Doesn't refer to the right instance of the module. Instead it uses the last instances all the time, even if i click a marker on the first map.
       clickMarker( idx, data );
});
```

If i put a console.log($el) in the `clickMarker` function, it always returns the second map. Any suggestions to make it work?

Comment: side-note, `$.each( data, function( key, value ) {createMarker( key, value );});` can be reduced to `$.each(createMarker);`

Comment: @KevinB Thanks, any ideas for my other problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never defined `$elTitle` and `$elDescription`, therefore, when you set them, they were being set globally on `window`. The second call overwrote the value set in the first.

To fix, simply modify this line:

```
$elCanvas,
```

to

```
$elCanvas,
$elTitle,
$elDescription,
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K9mqz/4/ (now there is a layout problem)

I found this by setting a breakpoint inside the `openOverlay` method and inspecting the available variables. I initially didn't see `$elTitle`, so i started digging till i found it on `window`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, never thought of that!

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are seeing is expected because you have one instance of the object `map` and your click handler .
If you don't know the number of maps you are going to need, I suggest using an array `map = [];` and pass the `map` object to the createMarker function `createMarker( idx, data, map[0]);` . Hope that helps.

```
markers = [];
maps = []; //pass one instance to the function bellow
function createMarker( idx, data, map ) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng( data.lat, data.lng ),
            map: map,
            title: data.title
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function( e ) {
            // THIS SHOULD WORK BECAUSE YOU ARE ADDING THE MARKER TO EACH MAP INSTANCE
            clickMarker( idx, data );
        });
    marker.setMap(map); //set the marker to the map instance you passed to the function 
    markers.push(marker);   //keep all the markers in one array and you can clear them easy 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually i have multiple instances of my module. At the very bottom of the script i used this code to support multiple maps on one page: `$map.each( function() {googleMaps().init( this );});`. So there should be multiple instances (in this case two). The problem is just inside this google maps click event listener...